# Hiding a workbook while being able to close others

Tags: excel, vba

I got a workbook that automatically opens a UserForm. 
The workbook itself I hide using `Application.Visible = False` 
While in the UserForm the user is able to create a new workbook (.CSV file)  and this all works.

But if the user tries to close the newly created workbook it will ask if you want to save it AND also want to save the original workbook (closing it in the process). If I select `No` on the first menu (new workbook) and cancel on the second (the original workbook) both workbooks remain open. If I don't select cancel on the second menu both will close.

Is there a way to hide my workbook and later on closing a different workbook without being forced to close the hidden workbook?

Update:
A current workaround I have is putting a button on the UserForm to close any newly created workbook with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` enabled during this process (and of course setting it to `true` after) .

Comment: My mind was leaning towards your update as well

Comment: Yea it kinda "fixes" the problem as long as the user remembers to use the Userform instead of clicking the actual X at the top right corner.

Comment: Is your intention to close the workbook without saving?

Comment: Sharing the code you use to create the workbook and close it would enable us to provide a more informed answer.

Comment: open the new workbook in a *separate* Excel instance. that way closing the new workbook will have no effect on the state of the hidden workbook

Comment: @ScottHoltzman as in there are 2 Excel icon's at the bottom of the screen? 
It already does that.

Comment: @Xabier
After the data is copied just a simple ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=""Filename and location", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows

Comment: @A.Bakker - two icons doesn't necessarily mean two instances of the application. you can force it by `Dim xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'or use early binding` and then work off that application